# Ubuntu 16.04 Unrecognized OpenGL version

Tags: android, ubuntu, opengl-es, virtualbox, genymotion

Genymotion freeze with: "Starting virtual device".

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Genymotion 2.8.1
  -- cleared cache,
  -- total removed, and install again,
  -- removed all virtual devices and download and installed new devices
  -- `genymotion.log` in `.Genymobile` folder without errors,
  -- `genymotion-player.log` in `.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom Phone - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 768x1280` folder:

```
bře 6 18:57:08 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Unrecognized OpenGL version
bře 6 18:57:08 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

VirtualBox 5.1.14
  -- total removed, and install again,
  -- others virtual devices runs correctly (i.e.: others Linux OS),

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 (command:`glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`)

[image: Genymotion player Stuck here]
[image: But running in virtual box]

Similar: [as here](https://askubuntu.com/q/863046)

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: I am at the same condition :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can happen if your system has an ATI card. Removing the libdrm.so.2 file from Genymotion install directory should fix it (make a backup in case things go wrong!)

Comment: Yes I have ATI card, renamed that file and now virtual device is running 

Comment: I face the same problem on my Mac and it doesn't have the above mentioned file to delete.