# Ubuntu 16.10 Genymotion player doesn't boot

Tags: genymotion

I started with Android development and searched for good android emulator (since built-in avd manager from Android studio is too slow). I found Genymotion a good option. I added a device and when I'm starting it Genymotion player freezes and in logs I have "Unrecognized OpenGL version". I have libGL from Mesa package and the Nvidia video card is installed in my computer. How can I solve that?

Edited: I have genymotion 2.8.1 from here: https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

So, the player just freezes at "Starting virtual device..." (like on screen below):

[image: Player error]

Logs during player session:

```
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [Adb] adb found at "/home/vkalashnykov/programs/Android/SDK/platform-tools/adb"
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtual device configured
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtualization engine configured
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "nexuss34")
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Trying to log in as "vityoube"
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtual Machine status: off
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Start the device...
mar 22 20:52:54 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "nexuss34", "--nic1", "hostonly")
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] "User vityoube (vityoube@gmail.com) logged on Hub"
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Pending calls: 0
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "nexuss34", "--hostonlyadapter1", "vboxnet2")
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Activation failed. Error: 9 - "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN"
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "nexuss34", "--nictype1", "virtio")
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "nexuss34", "--cableconnected1", "on")
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "nexuss34", "genymotion_player_version", "1")
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:55 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "nexuss34", "genymotion_vm_name", "nexuss34")
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "nexuss34")
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("startvm", "nexuss34", "--type", "headless")
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "nexuss34")
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtual Machine started.
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Waiting for an IP address...
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:52:56 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:57 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:52:57 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:58 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:52:58 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:52:59 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:52:59 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:53:00 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:53:00 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:53:01 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:53:02 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:53:03 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "nexuss34", "androvm_ip_management")
mar 22 20:53:03 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
mar 22 20:53:03 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Genymotion system started. Attributed IP address:  "192.168.58.101"
mar 22 20:53:03 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Unrecognized OpenGL version
mar 22 20:53:03 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

Comment: Which version of Genymotion is it? Can you add the relevant parts of the log file to the question? The error message looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632576/ubuntu-16-04-unrecognized-opengl-version/42690358 but this was with an ATI card.

Comment: Added logs from player to question.

Comment: What is interesting, that in virtualbox the device is normally running and i can actually work with it, but genymotion, for some reason, cannot start it fully.

Comment: I can't access the logs. Maybe you can directly copy the last 10 or 20 lines inside your question?

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: I figured out what was the problem. I hadn't proprietary drivers from nvidia. After installling latest nvidia driver all is working. Thank you.